# undefined when if condition in js

Tags: javascript, node.js

The method below is used in Node.js to deal with an API request.
Even when req.query.foo is not undefined (has a value), it becomes undefined if this is used in if condition like below. And another req.query.foo becomes also undefined. When I get rid of req.query.foo from the if condition, the "console.log(req.query.foo)" has a value, instead of undefined.
Could you tell me how to solve this?
Thank you very much.

```
app.get("/api/v1/", function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  console.log(req.query.foo);
  if (req.query.foo != undefined) {
    const response = {
      name: "john",
      foo: "foo",
    };
    res.send(JSON.stringify(response));
  } else {
    const response = {
      name: "john",
    };
    res.send(JSON.stringify(response));
  }
});
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ET69SR4 — I can't reproduce the problem

Comment: Note: Use `res.json` instead of `res.setHeader` + `res.send` + `JSON.stringify` (this won't solve the problem, but does save reinventing the wheel and will shorten your code).

Answer (score -2):

change

```
if (req.query.foo != undefined) {
```

to

```
const { foo } = req.query;
if (foo) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: You've made two different changes here and not explained why either of them should solve the problem.

Comment: Using destructuring syntax to copy `foo` to a variable of its own is pointless shuffling of deckchairs on the titanic.

Comment: Testing `req.query.foo` instead of `req.query.foo != undefined` changes the meaning of the code in a way that is significant, but only in an edge case (i.e. when the request is for `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/?foo` where `foo` is defined but doesn't have a real value) which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: Destructuring might be good if he has more data to pull from that query.

Comment: Destructuring *might be good* but even if it is, it is completely irrelevant to solving the problem.